# Python logging - best way to intercept ERROR and CRITICAL level log methods?

Tags: python, oop, logging

Can anyone suggest the best way to intercept (that is, perform some custom functionality first, then perform the normal log method) for code using the standard Python logger, for log levels ERROR and CRITICAL?  However, I still want to be able to log at the DEBUG level (i.e. levels below ERROR do not need the special intercept).  The solution would need to work for Python 2.4 and 2.7.

Comment: Add a custom handler (set logLevel to logging.ERROR) and define some function in `emit`.

Comment: I refined my requirements a bit.  I need the logger to log at all levels from DEBUG up, but need the special functionality for ERROR and CRITICAL levels.

Comment: There is no limit to the number of handlers you can add (and each has its own log level).  Check the python documentation for an extensive how-to guide.